# Load data from Python pickle file in a loop?

Tags: python, pickle

In a small data-acquisition project we use the Python's `pickle` to store recorded data, i.e. for each "event" we add it to the output file `f` with

```
pkl.dump(event, f, pkl.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

where `import cPickle as pkl`.

In the analysis of the data we read each event, but in contrast to a normal file where processing can be one in a rather elegant way:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        do_something(line)
```

looping over all the data in a pickle file this becomes a bit more awkward:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    try:
        while True:
            event = pkl.load(f)
            do_something(event)
    except (EOFError, UnpicklingError):
        pass
```

Is it possible to make pickle reading more like the example for regular files above?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, indeed. Use this generator below to make the events readable in a loop:

```
def pickleLoader(pklFile):
    try:
        while True:
            yield pkl.load(pklFile)
    except EOFError:
        pass
```

Now you can simply write:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for event in pickleLoader(f):
        do_something(event)
```